# Using XSL transforms to compare two nodes and then delete one

Tags: xml, xslt

XSLT newbie - I'm trying to use XSL transforms to compare and merge XML data from two different locations.

The data currently looks like this:

```
<root>
  <table1>
    <product>12345</product>
    <dateCreated>2015-06-04</dateCreated>
    <dateCompleted></dateCompleted>
  </table1>
  <table2>
    <dateCreated>2015-08-28T06:34:00</dateCreated>
    <dateCompleted></dateCompleted>
  </table2>
</root>
```

and this is how it needs to be:

```
<root>
  <newtable>
    <product>12345</product>
    <dateCreated>2015-08-28T06:34:00</dateCreated>
    <dateCompleted></dateCompleted>
  </newtable>
</root>
```

Essentially, I need to check if /table2/dateCreated exists, and has a value, and   if yes, put that node in the final XML.

The XSL file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table1/dateCreated | table2/dateCreated">
    <xsl:if test="table2/dateCreated !=''">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="table2/dateCreated"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously I'm at a loss as to what is happening - any assistance is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="table1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table1">
    <newtable>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </newtable>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dateCreated">
    <xsl:variable name="alt" select="/root/table2/dateCreated" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string($alt)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$alt"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I've done some XSLT already, but would you mind explaining why this transformation does not add a second `dateCreated` to table1?

Comment: @Stacky I am not sure I understand your question. The original `table1` has only one `dateCreated`. The stylesheet above copies its tags and puts a value inside them. That value is either the new value from `table2` - if it exists - or the existing value.

Comment: @Stacky: I guess you are coming from a procedural/OOP programming background and are thinking in it. XSLT-transformations are NOT done inplace(meaning you have data as in an array on which you operate). Instead XSLT is functional(think in functional paradigm with immutable data objects, every op creates a new data object). So in this case you have three data "objects": two input(table1 and table2) and one output(result=table3). The code above selects either table1 or table2 and copies it to table3, so one of the input "objects" is discarded by design.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - thank you so much! That's exactly what I was trying to achieve - I was hoping to do without using the named keys, but I guess this is just easier.

Also, while the XSLT above works well when the second **dateCreated** node has a value, it doesn't work when there is no value. I updated the test expression to `test="$alt != ''"` - is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I was referring to the `<xsl:variable>` directive. Appreciate your help again - I've accepted your answer!

Comment: @smkndblvr The variable is used to reduce the number of times the alternative `dateCreated` needs to be fetched from the other branch. You can do without it, but why would you want to?

Comment: Thanks Michael - it's just that I'm concerned from a performance perspective - I have another 20 fields that need to go through a similar transform. I haven't done any load tests yet, but, that will be a problem for another day :)